# How can i update the ColumnDataSource by an "selected.on_change()" event?

Tags: bokeh, python-3.7

First, I created a scatter plot out of geogr. coordinates. If i click on one of these circles a second line-plot next to that scatter plot shows further informations depending on what circle i've clicked. That means i have to update the current ColumnDataSource shown in the line-plot by a new one. But if i click on one of those circles the current Source will not be updated. The line-plot still shows the dataset of the old Source.

I'll try to give you a short example of what i've done so far:

```py
def callback(attr, old, new):

    # Depending on what circle i've clicked i start a SQL request
    # to gain my dataset i want to plot and the new title of the diagram.

    # To change the title actually works:
    line_plot.title.text = 'new_title'

    # "source_new_values" is a ColumnDataSource created out of a 
    # SQL-request of my database.
    # To change the current source doesn't work. The line-plot is still
    # showing the old dataset. 
    source_current_values = source_new_values 


scatter_plot = figure(x_axis_label='lat', y_axis_label='lon')
scatter_plot.circle(x='long', y='lat', source=source_coordinates)

# I use the indices to identify what circle was clicked.
source_coordinates.selected.on_change('indices', callback)


line_plot = figure(x_axis_label='time', x_axis_type='datetime', 
                                        y_axis_label='values', title='title')

line_plot.line(x='date', y='value', source=source_current_values)
```

Comment: Ok, i got it. I'm not able to update the source by a ColumnDataSource, but by a Dictionary using: source_current_values.data = Dict("some content")

Comment: As a project maintainer, it is better when questions on SO have accepted answers. As a courtesy I would ask you to answer and self-accept, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for tat Problem is I'm not able to update the source by a ColumnDataSource, but by a Dictionary using:

```py
   source_current_values.data = Dict("some content")
```